# Convert a PEM certificate file and a private key to PKCS12 with vs without CA

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, openssl, certificate, pkcs#12

I'm trying to convert a pem certificate to pfx (pkcs12) in order to connect to aws iot.

I'm using this command in cli:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt
```

I found out that I manage to connect either way if I add the CA or if I don't ([AmazonRootCA1.pem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/managing-device-certs.html#server-authentication)).

The question is: does it matter in terms of security? Is it any less secure if I don't include the CA when generating the pfx?

The generated pfx is different when including the CA vs without.

Note that I'm limited by a library that doesn't have a way to include the CA cert when generating the pfx, hence this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does it matter in terms of security?

No.

> Is it any less secure if I don't include the CA when generating the pfx?

No.

When validating the certificate, the chain is checked up to the root certificate.
Either the parent certificates are already present in the store of the one who does the validation (which meant trusted), or the chain comes with the certificate (to import it or use it as local store), or the AIA extension is utilized to download the chain on demand. The second and third options will not result in a valid chain when the root is not already known.